# display random image on mouse click on java

Tags: java, image, jframe, mouseevent

I want to display random images on a  mouse click event in java.
Like for every mouse click, a random pic pop's up.
But the Images won't show up when I compile my code.
The J frame window pops up but not my image, and nothing happens when I click

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DisplayMascot extends Component {

   private BufferedImage m2012, m2013, m2014, m2015;
   public BufferedImage img;
   public DisplayMascot(){
    try {
        m2012 = ImageIO.read(new File("gishwhes2012.png"));
        m2013 = ImageIO.read(new File("gishwhes2014-full-logo.png"));
        m2014= ImageIO.read(new File("mongilianbranding.jpg"));
        m2015 = ImageIO.read(new File("gishwhes2015-full-logo.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int i = rand.nextInt(4-1+1)+1;

    if (i==1)
        img = m2012;
    else if (i==2)
        img = m2013;
    else if (i==3)
        img = m2014;
    else if (i==4)
        img = m2015;
   }

   public void paint(Graphics g){//dram image
      g.drawImage(img,0,0,null);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't extend Component to display an image at its preferred size. Instead you can just use a `JLabel`. Then when you want to change the image you can just use:

```
label.setIcon( new ImageIcon(...) );
```

Don't create 4 variables to represent each image. What if you ever want to handle 10 images? Now you need 10 variables and your nested if statement becomes much larger.

Instead you can create an `ArrayList` to hold the images. Then when you want to display a random image you can use the `shuffle(...`) method of the ArrayList. Then you can take the first image in the List and use it for the Icon of the label.

Comment: thanks. I updated my code but I'm still having problems. I wrote the new code. could you check it please?